# Angularjs routing with ngroute and ngview does not work for me.Clicking on a link does not load the intended page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

There are some 3 links(Home, About, Contact) in the index.html file. On clicking them, I should be able to display new messages/html(home.html, contact.html, about.html) files as defined in script js. But that does not happen.

There are otherwise no errors while doing an "inspect element' in chrome.

The url on clicking on contact is :
file:///C:/Users/Sonali%20Sinha/Desktop/demo/omg/index.html#contact

The code files are as below.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="scotchApp">
<head>    
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a>   </li>
     </ul>
<div id="main">
 {{ message }}
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : '/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : '/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : '/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
    });

    // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
    scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
    });
```

home.html

```
<div>
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

contact.html

```
<div>
<h1>Contact Page</h1>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

about.html

```
<div>
<h1>About Page</h1>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

The directory structure is as below.

demo/omg/index.html
All files are inside omg.

Guys, I am stuck with this for a day now.:-( 
I am just a day old in angularjs. Please be kind and help me out.
Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Can you please add the directory structure you are using for the project as well?

Comment: It looks like you have an additional space in the src attribute. It should be `angular-route.js` instead of `angular- route.js`.

Comment: Hi Wayne, the space is not there in my actual html file. i think I might have messed up here while pasting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things :

- Run it behind an Apache as JB mentioned above.
- Remove the locationProvider block, it worked for me.

Comment: I was about to answer same. $locationProvider should not be in $routeProvider

Answer (score 0):

You're serving the app from the file system (i.e. using a `file://` URL), instead of service it from a web server (i.e. using an `http://` URL). You can't do AJAX requests on file system URLs. And Angular routing needs to do AJAX requests to load the views.

Comment: I tried that too. I was placing the folder inside /XAMPP/htdocs and running it as http://localhost/. But did not work!

Comment: Open your browser dev tools, look for error messages in the *Console* panel. Look at the requests in the *Network* panel and check if you get 404 or other kinds of error responses.

Comment: Yes I was doing that. there were no errors. LocationProvider casued the problem. Thanks :-)